nodejs is not run in vs code terminal
PS C:\Users\Admin> npm -v
Program 'npm. cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

am try all video hacks to solve this problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Add this path in system variables:
`C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Path -> Edit -> New -> <paste the path above>
